# Error: SocketException: Connection reset by peer (OS Error: Connection reset by peer, errno = 104) flutter FTPConnect

Tags: flutter, dart, ftp-client

I use image_picker and ftpconnect to take a picture and upload it into distant FTP Server, but when my program is at ftpConnect.uploadFile(filePath) I have the following error:

```
\-- Error: SocketException: Connection reset by peer (OS Error: Connection reset by peer, errno = 104), address = \<host\>, port = \<port\>
```

I have my upload method :

```
Future<void> uploadFtp(File filepath, String code) async {
  FTPConnect ftpConnect = FTPConnect('host',port:21, user:'user', pass:'pass', debug: true,securityType: SecurityType.FTPES, timeout: 30);
  await _log('Connecting to FTP');
  bool connection = await ftpConnect.connect();
  await _log('Connection : ' + (connection ? 'SUCCESSFULLY' : 'FAILED'));
    try {
      bool change = await ftpConnect.changeDirectory('palette');
      await _log(
          'Change directory : ' + (change ? 'SUCCESSFULLY' : 'FAILED'));
      String dir = path.dirname(filepath.path);
      String newName = path.join(dir, '$code.jpg');
      filepath = File(filepath.path).renameSync(newName);
      await _log('Uploading ... : ${filepath}');
      bool res = await ftpConnect.uploadFile(filepath);
      await _log('file uploaded: ' + (res ? 'SUCCESSFULLY' : 'FAILED'));
    } catch(e) {
      await _log('Error: ${e.toString()}');
    } finally {
      await ftpConnect.disconnect();
    }
}
```

```
Future<void> _log(String log) async {
  print(log);
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
}
```

I set debug as true to see in FTPConnect or FTPSocket class if I can see any details and I saw this :
[image]

I checked my FTP configuration by sending files from a windows FTPClient(FileZilla) and an Android(AndFTP), and both worked. My FTP Server use FTPS(Explicit FTP over TLS/SSL).

Comment: Have you tried the same exact file when you tried it from Windows?

Comment: Yes, with Android too.

Comment: did you find a solution for this?